# Sending HTTP Post to Parse Platform from AT Command

Tags: parse-platform, at-command

I am trying to send a post http request to the following that works in other platforms but have problem formatting it in AT Command:

```
AT+CHTTPACT="parseapi.back4app.com",443
WAIT=1
POST https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/sensor HTTP/1.1
X-Parse-Application-Id: GiFxhzih1h49s1Zv9P5A5cewnPt5IDx7hultl46j
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ksduaNwsr8Pctjkr1lBP6jfhA2Tb40ghNl2RTmB3
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
{"sensor":"55"}
<cr><lf>^z<cr><lf>
```

This is the error I get:

### The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 3chKxtt4JUxY0RHrSBoYqWp9mYdbZmelia7o1_7CtxFRM4e2WodH-w==

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add HOST header in the POST request mentioned here
https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM5320/sim52xx_http_application_note_v0.02.pdf

Bad request generally occurs when CloudFront couldn't identify which distribution it needs to connect to.

Comment: You just told me what I asked. I am looking for solution not question.

Comment: Try with HOST: parseapi.back4app.com in the POST request, it should work.

Comment: Nope, I know this is the problem and you need to test and verify it.

Comment: And I know you are 10 steps behind me. Dont just throw something if you are just guessing.

Comment: Don't be shy to update if you find out that this was solved after adding HOST header.

Comment: The codes are there and you can get a response as the keys are current. I have tried with a million combination uusing HOST URL etc.